KeyManager doesn't work when I try to make a HTTPS call with OkHttp through an HTTP Proxy
Introduction:
I am trying to program in Java a call to a public API (it is not a known API, but the domain is public and can be accessed from any computer with internet access).
To make the call, the owner of the API has sent me the openAPi (v3.0.1) specification.
Due to maintenance/industrialization issues, it has been decided to use openapi-generator-maven-plugin (v7.5.0) to generate the client automatically via the openAPI specification.
The plugin uses OkHttp3 by default to generate the client classes.
The API I have to call has a peculiarity, it is programmed so that it is mandatory to send a client certificate to authenticate.
If I make the call from an environment that has direct access, it works correctly.
If I make the call from an environment that needs to go through an HTTP Proxy, it does not work correctly.
Configuration (Variables replaced due to confidentiality issues):
certConf:
  apiKey: {API_KEY}
  urlService: {URL_SERVICE}
  keyStorePath: ".\\src\\main\\resources\\{CLIENT_CERTIFICATE}.pfx"
  keyStorePassword: {CLIENT_CERTIFICATE_PASSWORD}
  keyStoreType: "PKCS12"
  certificatValidePath: ".\\src\\main\\resources\\{API_CERTIFICATE_CHAIN}.crt"

proxy:
  externe:
    port: 8080
    address: {PROXY_IP}

Direct call:
If I make the direct call it works correctly ->
package {MY_CONF_PACKAGE};

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Proxy;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;

import javax.net.ssl.KeyManager;
import javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import {MY_GENERATED_SOURCES_PACKAGE}.ApiInterface;
import {MY_GENERATED_SOURCES_PACKAGE}.ApiClient;
import {MY_CONF_PACKAGE}.CertConf;
import {MY_CONF_PACKAGE}.ProxyConf;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;

@Configuration
public class MyClientConf {
    
    
    @Autowired
    private CertConf certConf;
    
    @Autowired
    private ProxyConf proxyConf;
    
    
    @Bean
    public ApiInterface apiInterfaceController() throws UnrecoverableKeyException, KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, IOException {
        var apiInterface = new ApiInterface();
        
        apiInterface.setCustomBaseUrl(certConf.getUrlService());
        apiInterface.setApiClient(apiClient());
        
        return apiInterface;
    }

    @Bean
    public ApiClient apiClient() throws UnrecoverableKeyException, KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, IOException {
        var apiClient = new ApiClient();
        
//      apiClient.setHttpClient(new OkHttpClient.Builder().proxy(new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(proxyConf.getExterne().getAddress(), proxyConf.getExterne().getPort())))
//               .build());
        apiClient.setKeyManagers(initKeyManager(certConf.getKeyStorePath(), certConf.getKeyStorePassword(), certConf.getKeyStoreType()));
        apiClient.setSslCaCert(new FileInputStream(certConf.getCertificatValidePath()));
        apiClient.setApiKey(certConf.getApiKey());      
        
        return apiClient;
    }
    
    
    private KeyManager[] initKeyManager(String keyStorePath, String keyStorePassword, String keyStoreType) throws KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, IOException, UnrecoverableKeyException {

        try(var keyStoreFile = new FileInputStream(keyStorePath)) {
            
            var keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
        
            keyStore.load(keyStoreFile, keyStorePassword.toCharArray());
            var keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, keyStorePassword.toCharArray());
            return keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers();
        
        }

    }
    

}

This line does its job correctly (I manage to encrypt the connection so that it is HTTPS saying that the {API_CERTIFICATE_CHAIN} of the API I call is trusted) ->
    apiClient.setSslCaCert(new FileInputStream(certConf.getCertificatValidePath()));
    

If it was not configured correctly I would get the following error ->
PKIX path building failed
This line does its job correctly (I manage to pass the server authentication barrier by sending the {CLIENT_CERTIFICATE}) ->
apiClient.setKeyManagers(initKeyManager(certConf.getKeyStorePath(), certConf.getKeyStorePassword(), certConf.getKeyStoreType()));

If it was not configured correctly I would get the following error ->
403 : Forbidden : Missing certificate
Call through an HTTP Proxy doesn't work:
If I make the call through a proxy it works partially ->
package {MY_CONF_PACKAGE};

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Proxy;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;

import javax.net.ssl.KeyManager;
import javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import {MY_GENERATED_SOURCES_PACKAGE}.ApiInterface;
import {MY_GENERATED_SOURCES_PACKAGE}.ApiClient;
import {MY_CONF_PACKAGE}.CertConf;
import {MY_CONF_PACKAGE}.ProxyConf;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;

@Configuration
public class MyClientConf {
    
    
    @Autowired
    private CertConf certConf;
    
    @Autowired
    private ProxyConf proxyConf;
    
    
    @Bean
    public ApiInterface apiInterfaceController() throws UnrecoverableKeyException, KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, IOException {
        var apiInterface = new ApiInterface();
        
        apiInterface.setCustomBaseUrl(certConf.getUrlService());
        apiInterface.setApiClient(apiClient());
        
        return apiInterface;
    }

    @Bean
    public ApiClient apiClient() throws UnrecoverableKeyException, KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, IOException {
        var apiClient = new ApiClient();
        
        apiClient.setHttpClient(new OkHttpClient.Builder().proxy(new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(proxyConf.getExterne().getAddress(), proxyConf.getExterne().getPort())))
                 .build());
        apiClient.setKeyManagers(initKeyManager(certConf.getKeyStorePath(), certConf.getKeyStorePassword(), certConf.getKeyStoreType()));
        apiClient.setSslCaCert(new FileInputStream(certConf.getCertificatValidePath()));
        apiClient.setApiKey(certConf.getApiKey());      
        
        return apiClient;
    }
    
    
    private KeyManager[] initKeyManager(String keyStorePath, String keyStorePassword, String keyStoreType) throws KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, IOException, UnrecoverableKeyException {

        try(var keyStoreFile = new FileInputStream(keyStorePath)) {
            
            var keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
        
            keyStore.load(keyStoreFile, keyStorePassword.toCharArray());
            var keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, keyStorePassword.toCharArray());
            return keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers();
        
        }

    }
    

}

This line does its job correctly (I manage to encrypt the connection so that it is HTTPS saying that the {API_CERTIFICATE_CHAIN} of the API I call is trusted) ->
    apiClient.setSslCaCert(new FileInputStream(certConf.getCertificatValidePath()));
    

If it was not configured correctly I would get the following error ->
PKIX path building failed
This line does not do its job correctly (I can't manage to pass the server authentication barrier by sending the {CLIENT_CERTIFICATE}) ->
apiClient.setKeyManagers(initKeyManager(certConf.getKeyStorePath(), certConf.getKeyStorePassword(), certConf.getKeyStoreType()));

I get the following error ->
403 : Forbidden : Missing certificate
This line partially does its job ->
    apiClient.setHttpClient(new OkHttpClient.Builder().proxy(new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(proxyConf.getExterne().getAddress(), proxyConf.getExterne().getPort())))
             .build());
             

I manage to make the call through the proxy because if it is incorrectly configured I would get the following error ->
Connection timed out
Problem:
I have come to the conclusion that the origin of the problem is that the HTTP Proxy does not redirect correctly the {CLIENT_CERTIFICATE}. There is an interaction that I cannot understand between the Proxy and the KeyManager.
Note:
The problem is not caused by the configuration of the flows and the HTTP Proxy (I have made the call with POSTMAN both with the HTTP Proxy and without it and it works correctly).
The environment from which I call with the HTTP Proxy does not have direct access to the API and is different from the one from which I make the direct call.
Thanks in advance

I have solved the problem but partially. If I compile and launch the application with a jdk and a more modern version of java it works. This solves the problem but I can't understand what exactly solves it, since the project is made in Java 11 and compiles and works correctly except for this HTTP Proxy error.
JDK11 -> All the project works except this strange interaction with the HTTP Proxy
JDK17 -> Resolves the error of the HTTP Proxy

I have solved the problem but partially. If I compile and launch the application with a JDK and a more modern version of java it works. This solves the problem but I can't understand what exactly solves it, since the project is made in Java 11 and compiles and works correctly except for this HTTP Proxy error.
JDK11 -> All the project works except this strange interaction with the HTTP Proxy
JDK17 -> Resolves the error of the HTTP Proxy
This is a problem, because migrating the application is not going to be trivial.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
